# How to see log of Windows Powershell commands and output from previous sessions?

Tags: powershell

How can I see a log of all the commands I have typed into Windows Powershell? For example, I write a bunch of commands in the evening, shut down my computer, then when I log back on the next morning. Is there a store of the Powershell commands and output?

Comment: See if [Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7.3) or [Get-History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-history?view=powershell-7.3) would serve the purpose.

Comment: @Scepticalist That's not true. I can certainly get last entered commands by pressing the `up` key after closing and reopening a PowerShell session and even after a reboot.

Comment: Just a suggestion - Visual Studio code with Powershell extension helps to save the history.